# How to disable only wp root paths in wordpress-rest-api?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How can I disable the root-paths so that the api still works but all the listings at the root are disabled ?

Wordpress has the wp2json api like
wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
wp-json/wp/v2/users/
wp-json/wp/v2/
wp-json/wp/v2/my-custom-posts

I tried this with route filter with empty function, but it gave erros.